# Finding position of an element in vector of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Let `A` be a vector of vectors of type `double`, i.e. `vector<vector<double> > A` and `B` be the same but for integers, i.e. `vector<vector<int> > B`. Assume that size of `A` and `B` is the same (and sizes of every nested vectors are equal as well).

I would like to check if `j` is contained in `i`-th vector of `B` by using `std::find`, so I write `std::find(B[i].begin(), B[i].end(), j) != B[i].end()`. Now, if that is `true` I would like to return value in `A` corresponding to `[i][position_of_j_found_in_B[i]]`. How can I accomplish this?

My code is as follows:

```
    class SparseMatrix
    {
        private:
            vector<vector<double> > entries_;
            vector<vector<int> > columnIndices_;
        public:
            SparseMatrix();
            SparseMatrix(vector<vector<double> >,vector<vector<int> >);
            ~SparseMatrix();

            // getters
            vector<vector<double> > getEntries();
            vector<vector<int> > getColIndices();

            double operator()(const unsigned int&, const unsigned int&);

            vector<int> size();

    };

    SparseMatrix::SparseMatrix() { };

    SparseMatrix::SparseMatrix(vector<vector<double> > values, vector<vector<int> > colInd) : entries_(values), columnIndices_(colInd) { };

    SparseMatrix::~SparseMatrix() { };

    vector<vector<double> > SparseMatrix::getEntries() { return entries_; }

    vector<vector<int> > SparseMatrix::getColIndices() { return columnIndices_; }

    double SparseMatrix::operator()(const unsigned int i, const unsigned int j)
    {
        assert(i <= (*this).size()[0] && j <= (*this).size()[1]);

        auto it = find(columnIndices_[i].begin(),columnIndices_[i].end(), j);

        if(it != columnIndices_[i].end())
            return entries_[i][it - columnIndices_[i].begin()];
        return 0.0;
    }

vector<int> SparseMatrix::size() // returns dimensions of the matrix
{
    vector<int> dim(2); // stores dimensions of the matrix
    dim[0] = columnIndices_.size(); // numbers of rows in a matrix

    int temp = 0;
    vector<vector<int> >::iterator i;
    for(i=columnIndices_.begin(); i != columnIndices_.end(); ++i)
    {
        if(*max_element((*i).begin(),(*i).end()) > temp) // if maximal element in i-th vector of columnIndices_ is greater then current (temp)
            temp = *max_element((*i).begin(),(*i).end()); // update current biggest with new one
    }
    dim[1] = temp;
    return dim;
}
```

And my `main()` function is

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<vector<double> > values {{3.0, 1.0}, {2.0}, {5.0, 4.0}};
    vector<vector<int> > columns {{1,3}, {1}, {2,3}};

    SparseMatrix A(values,columns);

    cout << "Matrix A has dimensions " << A.size()[0] << "x" << A.size()[1] << "." << endl; // works fine

    cout << A.getEntries()[0][0] << " " <<  A(0,0) << endl; // I expect the same output...
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: post the actual code you already have

Comment: position = it - Y[i].begin()

Comment: @x1Mike7x, by that you mean I should define new iterator: `vector<int>::iterator position;` then assign `position = it - Y[i].begin()` and in `if` I should `return X[i][*position]`? Then it does not work...

Comment: @user2871983, no, 'position' it's just a size_t variable.

Comment: Still, it does not work... Maybe it is the case that this `foo()` functon is actually an overloaded parentheses operator inside my class. I declare it as: `double SomeClass::operator()(const unsigned int& i, const unsigned int& j)`, where `X` and `Y` are private vectors of vectors in this class.

Comment: And, what's wrong with new code, it works exactly as you want, it return 3 0 as expected.

Comment: `A(0,0)` should return `3.0` which is the first element in the matrix given by this weird representation. Instead it returns `0`. The correct value is obtained by `getEntries()` method which does not satisfy me...

Comment: No, A(0, 0) should return 0.0 according to your description, because in `B`(`columns`) in vector with index 0, we search value 0, and there are no such value in {1,3}, so we return 0.0, and I suppose this right behavior for sparse matrix

Comment: OK, I see it now... then this kind of overloaded parentheses are not what I wanted :/ The problem here is that these two vectors of vectors (initialized as in `main()`) are supposed to represent the matrix `A={{3.0, 0, 1.0}, {2.0, 0, 0}, {0, 5.0, 4.0}}` and I wish to somehow extract from these two vectors of vectors each value in `A` as `A(i,j)`.

Comment: I add to my answer the possible implementation of SparseMatrix

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution the solution of original problem:

```
double foo(const vector<vector<double> >& X, const vector<vector<int> >& Y, unsigned int i, unsigned int j)
{
  auto  it = find(Y[i].begin(),Y[i].end(), j);

  if (it != Y[i].end())
      return X[i][it - Y[i].begin()];

  return 0.0;
}
```

P.S. I pass vector by reference because for optimization, for the same reason I pass unsigned int by value.

Here is example of SparseMatrix implementation:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

class SparseMatrix final {
public:
    explicit SparseMatrix(const std::vector<double>& full_matrix) {
        static constexpr double EPS = 1e-16;
        const size_t N = std::sqrt(full_matrix.size());
        assert((N * N) == full_matrix.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            for (size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
                if (std::fabs(full_matrix[i * N + j]) > EPS)
                    data_.push_back(std::make_tuple(full_matrix[i * N + j], i, j));
    }
    double operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const {
        auto it = std::find_if(data_.begin(), data_.end(),
                       [&i, &j](const std::tuple<double, size_t, size_t>& elm) {
                           return std::get<1>(elm) == i && std::get<2>(elm) == j;
                 });
        return it == data_.end() ? 0.0 : std::get<0>(*it);
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::tuple<double, size_t, size_t>> data_;
};

int main()
{
    SparseMatrix A({3.0, 0, 1.0,
            2.0, 0, 0,
                0, 5.0, 4.0});
    std::cout << A(0, 0) << '\n';
}
```

Note this SparseMatrix good for study projects, but for every day usage,
the best way to use already existing classes for linear algebra for C++.

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not work for me... See this comment [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465732/finding-position-of-an-element-in-vector-of-vectors/33466804#comment54719110_33465732)

Comment: without example that reproduce your problem it is impossible to help